# How to count unique visitors in an nginx access.log?

Tags: nginx, visitors, logging

I tried this, but it always returns 1.

```
grep "\[10/Nov/2012" /path/to/access.log | cut -d" " -f1 | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

Comment: Do you use custom log on your nginx or a default configuration ?

Comment: default configuration

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
tom@webserver:/srv/tomoconnor/logfiles$ awk '/10.Nov.2012/ {print $1}' < access_log|sort|uniq |wc -l
169
```

I prefer awk to grep and cut, as you can tell it which field you want. Then just sort, uniq, and count.

You can get a count of how many hits per IP if you remove `wc -l` and make `uniq` into `uniq -c`

Comment: Thanks Tom, it work's. I can't close this question, don't know why...

Comment: You have to tick the big green check mark next to my answer.  The problem might be that you're logged in with the wrong user account.  The original one has your username with 2 separate words.